# CSS: is it possible to enlarge with animation an element in place with CSS?

Tags: animation, css

Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzgha/). Now that CSS animations are almost in full swing, I'd like to do something like this in CSS: when mouse comes over an element (`.box`), it is enlarged with an animation, its center stays in the same place and all other elements stay where they are.

If I knew the elements' widths, I guess I could do that with a wrapper element for each element and use relative positioning for the element (`.box`) and animate it's width, height, left and top. But this example has variable with elements.

If it's not possible, any other suggestions for such an effect?

Comment: How's something like [this](http://minitech.github.com/) work for you? It scales it, but it might be okay. Source at https://github.com/minitech/minitech.github.com.

Comment: Check my comment for thirtydot's answer.

Comment: My answer was rushed, and there have since been better answers posted, so there's no point keeping mine around. The comment referred to everywhere was: "This is great, but is unfortunately usable only with very fast transitions. Check this jsfiddle ([jsfiddle.net/uzgha/5](http://jsfiddle.net/uzgha/5)) and see how the text is blurry until the animation is finished. It's like I did a zoom on an element, so the contents are not crisp :("

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use CSS3 transitions.

```
.box {
    -webkit-transition:  -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .2s ease-out; 
    transition: transform .2s ease-out; 
}
.box:hover {
   -webkit-transform:scale(2);
   -moz-transform:scale(2);
   -o-transform:scale(2);
   transform:scale(2);
}
```

See fidd.e: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/uzgha/6/

Comment: I have the same comment as for the answer from thirtydot.

Comment: I see the problem, but only in Webkit. In Opera and Firefox it looks like pure awesomeness. ;) It must be due to the text rendering in Webkit. I'm not sure, how you would fix this.

Comment: The text still moves left-right during a longer animation (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/uzgha/7/), but I guess I can live with that. I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, using transforms and transitions. Here's an update Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/wTbTf/

```
.container {-webkit-transform:translateZ(0); /* Stop webkit flicker bug */}
.box {
    postion:relative;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:-o-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition:transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}    
.box:hover {
    z-index:2; /* Put on top of others */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
    -o-transform:scale(1);
    transform:scale(1);
}
```

You can also scale down, as in: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/wTbTf/2/

Comment: I have the same comment as for the answer from thirtydot.

Comment: Yeah, the browser is actually scaling the element up, so blurring is aboslutely a side effect _(looks like Chrome re-renders text after the scale completes for cripsness)_. There's not too much you can do about this, it's more up to the browsers to better handle scaling text from this point on. `scale()` is absolutely what you want to use in this situation.

Comment: @duality_ Edited my answer to have a "scale down" fiddle. Same concept, but now the original scale will be post-animation: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/wTbTf/2/

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not a complete answer (so I'm not marking it as accepted) and also has a drawback: the text seems to move when animating, but this is my jsfiddle with no blurring, but unfortunately uses fixed width boxes (I know I didn't ask for this :), maybe someone can improve on my answer).

http://jsfiddle.net/5jfDC/1/